# Why useState makes the component to render twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

maybe some of you can open my eyes.

I don't understand why in this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-state-renders-twice-6r1xl
component App renders twice when mounted and clicking the button (console.log is called twice)

code:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClicked(!clicked);
  console.log(clicked);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>;
}
```

result:

```
false
false
true
true
```

it's just a functional component hooking `useState`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578158/why-does-usestate-cause-the-component-to-render-twice-on-each-update)

Answer (score 4):

It is because of `React.StrictMode` and this only happens in development. If you remove React.StrictMode you will get only 1 log.

For more details, check this thread on react repo:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074

Also check React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Check the app without StrictMode here: https://codesandbox.io/s/use-state-renders-twice-3vroc

Hope this helps!