# Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple bit of code here

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  function chaneNumber() {
    setNumber(state => state + 1);
  }

  console.log("here");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={chaneNumber}>Change number</button>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Every time I click the button, I get 2 logs in my console indicating that the component renders twice. I found one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934080/why-usestate-makes-the-component-to-render-twice) saying this is about strict mode, but I have not enabled strict mode. Why is this component rendering twice on each state update?

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-glitter-zu3p9?file=/src/App.js:0-360) link to try it out.

Comment: Probably because the app in in a React.StrictMode

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your App component is rendered within `React.StrictMode` which is what causes your code to run in strict mode and in strict mode the consoles are shown twice because each function is made to run twice in development mode

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Comment: I never noticed that CRA automatically add strict mode.

Comment: And I just spent hours trying to figure out why my components are being rendered twice... Should have read more about StrictMode first...^_^