# useState | useEffect without setting new state casues additional rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't find any information why this render is called twice ?

```js
const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState();

  console.log("RENDER TEST");
  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

When I remove

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState();
```

then the component is rendered only once.

The same happens with useEffect:

```js
const Test: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
   console.log("Component mounted");
  }, []);

  console.log("RENDER TEST");
  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Without useEffect the render is called only once.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578158/why-does-usestate-cause-the-component-to-render-twice-on-each-update/61578206#61578206)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening due to React's **StrictMode** in order to detect any problems and to want you about them. It runs only in development and not in production. In your application in **index.js** you will find that your **App** component is wrapped with **React.StrictMode** component. You can read more about it https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html