# Why useState hook causes unnecessarily re-render cycle in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why does just defining the state like this:

```
const [flipCardDeg, changeFCDeg] = useState(0);
```

in a normal function component cause an additional re-render cycle?
Instead of 1 re-render, it re-renders twice.

I know that if somewhere is used "changeFCDeg" to change the state it should re-render, that's OK. But why at the beginning, when initializing everything, it re-renders one more time?

Should I worry about having 2 re-renders instead of one, and if yes, how to deal with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578158/why-does-usestate-cause-the-component-to-render-twice-on-each-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React re-renders whenever it detects change.  You can try to get control over that by specifying exactly what it perceives as a change.  For example, like this:

```
const getMoreData = false
const [flipCardDeg, changeFCDeg] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('say something once')
  return () => {
    console.log('why say it again?')
  }
}, [getMoreData])  // will only run once unless getMoreData is changed
```