# React re-render simple component twice using hooks UseState and UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is to change the state variable when another state variable had changed.

I'm changing state inside UseEffect, which depends on a changed input text.
And it runs render twice.

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-re-render-twice-9qoo0?file=/src/App.js)

Just type something in input and check the console.

UPD: I'm already comment out <React.StrictMode> in index.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does useState cause the component to render twice on each update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578158/why-does-usestate-cause-the-component-to-render-twice-on-each-update)

Comment: Yes, because you are updating state twice, once in the onChange event handler and once in the useEffect method. Every state change results in a re-render. That is expected behaviour.

Comment: Don't console log in the functional component body, and definitely don't console log in the returned JSX, that is a side-effect in what *should* be a pure function. Use an effect to log state. Your component isn't *actually* rendering to the DOM twice. Learn the [component lifecycle](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) and you'll see why.