# ReactJS Component renders twice on state change

Tags: reactjs

I have component that I am working on but took it don to the bare minimum to exemplify my issue:

App:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(      
      <div className="App"><div style={{width:"500px", height:"300px",margin:"0 auto",marginTop:"100px"}}><PhnGrid/></div></div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

PhnGrid:

```
class PhnGrid extends React.Component{
    dataset=[{phonetype:"",phonenumber:""}]
    state = {rowcount:1}
    render(){      
        console.log(this.state)
        return(<h1>HELLO</h1>);
    }
}
export default PhnGrid;
```

When the `PhnGrid` component mounts (or when the state changes) `render` is called twice everytime.  Can anyone tell me what going on?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934080/why-usestate-makes-the-component-to-render-twice/60934105#60934105

Comment: Yash!  Yes and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **PureComponent** instead of **Component**!
PureComponent is exactly the same as Component except that it handles the shouldComponentUpdate method for you. When props or state changes, PureComponent will do a shallow comparison on both props and state. Component on the other hand won’t compare current props and state to next out of the box. Thus, the component will re-render by default whenever shouldComponentUpdate is called.

```
class PhnGrid extends React.PureComponent {
    dataset=[{phonetype:"",phonenumber:""}]
    state = {rowcount:1}
    render(){      
        console.log(this.state)
        return(<h1>HELLO</h1>);
    }
}
export default PhnGrid;
```